# Trying to plot hydrogen wave functions using Sympy module

Tags: python, physics, sympy

I'm trying to plot the radial part of the hydrogen wave function.

My idea was to use sympy.physics.hydrogen.R_nl as well as matplotlib and numpy.

Since the hydrogen.R_nl function returns a symbol string, I tried using the lambdify method to convert to a function that I would be able to plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sympy.abc import n, l, r, Z
from sympy.physics import hydrogen
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

R_nl = lambdify((n, l, r, Z), hydrogen.R_nl(n, l, r, Z))

Z = 1
n, l = 1, 0
r = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

plt.plot(r, R_nl(n, l, r, Z))
```

Upon execution I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-4-886beb2c570c> in <module>()
 ---> 13 plot(r, R_nl(n, l, r, Z))

 /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <lambda>(_Dummy_148, _Dummy_149, _Dummy_150, _Dummy_151)

NameError: name 'factorial' is not defined
```

Using sympy.plotting.plot instead of matplotlib.pyplot.plot doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: The package versions I'm using are sympy=1.1.1, numpy=1.14.3 and matplotlib=2.2.2

Comment: Could you post your packages versions? your code is working fine for me. I am using `sympy=1.3`, `numpy=1.14.5`, `matplotlib=2.2.2`.

Comment: Turns out there's a bug in Sympy that makes `lambdify((n, l, r, Z), hydrogen.R_nl(n, l, r, Z))` give the wrong result. I've [submitted a bug report](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15654), but in the meantime use the workaround described in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53807407/425458) below.

Comment: The workaround should also fix your `NameError` (but so would upgrading your Sympy package to the latest version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit: there's a bug in Sympy

Turns out there's a bug in Sympy that makes `lambdify((n, l, r, Z), hydrogen.R_nl(n, l, r, Z))` give the wrong result. I've submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15654). Basically, it comes down a conflict in the signatures of `assoc_laguerre` in Scipy and Sympy.

Until this gets fixed, you'll need to lambdify `R_nl` as so:

```
lambdify((n, l, r, Z), hydrogen.R_nl(n, l, r, Z), ('numpy', 'math', 'sympy'))
```

This explicitly specifies the list of modules that `lambdify` can use to evaluate the function that you pass it (same as the code in the **workaround** section below), and tells it not to use Scipy.

## The problem/solution

You code works as is. The Sympy folks have been actively fixing `lambdify` for a while, so you probably just have an old version. You should upgrade your version of Sympy.

## Workaround

If you can't upgrade, here's a workaround that will explicitly tell `lambdify` where to find the definition of `factorial`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sympy.abc import n, l, r, Z
from sympy.physics import hydrogen
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

R_nl = lambdify((n, l, r, Z), hydrogen.R_nl(n, l, r, Z), ('numpy', 'math', 'sympy'))

Z = 1
n, l = 1, 0
r = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

plt.plot(r, R_nl(n, l, r, Z))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your code, what you want to achieve is evaluate the function R_nl for Z=1, n=1, l=0 at different values of r. Here's how:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sympy.abc import n, l, r, Z
from sympy.physics import hydrogen
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

R_nl = lambdify(r, hydrogen.R_nl(1, 0, r, 1))
r = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

plt.plot(r, R_nl(r))
```